# Strange Syntax error on line 1 of php mySQL database creation

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
<html lang="en">
<body>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error)
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
// Create database
$sql = "CREATE DATABASE myDB";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)
{
    echo "Database created successfully";
}
else
{
    echo "Error creating database: " . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";
```

I am stumped as the SQL seems to have no issues in syntax yet we are getting the error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds     to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '<html lang="en">
<body>
    <?php
    $servername = "localhost"' at line 1
```

I saw a similar question earlier where the issue was in the first line of SQL but I do not see any issues there with syntax.

Comment: Your code looks ok to me

Comment: How is this file being used? Are you directly accessing from the browser? or is it included in another file? Please provide some more background regarding how this code is used or maybe some supplementary code as well

Comment: It is standalone at the moment, however it will be used by some javascript as reference data for a game

Comment: did you run `mysql < a.php` instead of `php a.php` ?

Comment: What do you mean? I am new to php and SQL...

Comment: I tested it on SQL Fiddle

Comment: What @microtony means is that the error suggests that you're sending the whole html file to the SQL interpreter instead of running the PHP code so that only the "CREATE DATABASE myDB" text is sent to the sql interpreter.

Comment: So how do I fix this thing?

Comment: The issue still appears when I run the code in the SQL interpreter without the html tags.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with the code you posted here. It must be related the 'interpreter' you mentioned. Possibly the whole point of a SQL 'interpreter' is to only execute actual SQL command strings and not html/php scripts. As other comments have said, your PHP code looks fine, the HTML in the file is normal, but the entire .php file contents are being delivered as the query to the SQL server instead of just a single SQL command. Try putting `CREATE DATABASE myDB;` as the only line in the file. If that works, you need a PHP parser instead of an SQL interpreter to execute this file.

Comment: Try putting quotes around the DB name: `$sql = "CREATE DATABASE \`myDB\`";`

Comment: I ran the interpreter with just the CREATE DATABASE myDB; but it didn't work, it gave me the same error.

Comment: Progress has been made, I was using the wrong thing on SQL Fiddle the new error is Unexpected parameter marker at position 29. Which makes even less sense to me.

Comment: What's 'the wrong thing'?

Comment: I was running as mySQL 5.6 instead of mySQL Server 2014